# Error al importar excel con ajax y php

Tags: php, ajax, excel

Tengo que importar datos desde un archivo xls de excel para lo cual utilizo ajax. Probando con csv se guarda el archivo en el servidor sin problema, pero al intentarlo con el xls no se guarda, con lo cual, no puedo realizar el resto de la tarea. Alguna solución?

Ajax:

```
        $.ajax({

        url: 'upload.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: dataForm,
        cache: false,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        beforeSend: function(){

            console.log('antes del envío');
        },
        success: function(data){

            console.log('success: '+data);
            $('#response').html(data);

        },
        error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {

            $('#response').html(jqXHR + " :: " + textStatus + " :: " + errorThrown);
        }

    });
```

upload.php:

```
if (isset($_FILES['file']['name'])) {
$targetPath = 'uploads/'.$_FILES['file']['name'];
$move = move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $targetPath);

if ( $move ) {
    echo "Archivo cargado con éxito";
}else{
    echo "Error al cargar el archivo";
}
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Crea un `FormData` para enviar los archivos, con PHP usa la variable `$_FILES` para manejar la respuesta

JS:

```javascript
$('#upload').on('click', function() {
    let file_data = $('#inputFile').prop('files')[0];
    let form_data = new FormData();
    form_data.append('file', file_data);
    $.ajax({
        url: 'upload.php',
        dataType: 'text',
        cache: false,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        data: form_data,                         
        type: 'post',
        success: function(resp){
            if (resp) { console.log(resp); }
        }
     });
});
```

PHP:

```php
<?php

    if ( 0 < $_FILES['file']['error'] ) {
        echo 'Error de subida: ' . $_FILES['file']['error'] . '<br>';
    }
    else {
        move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], 'uploads/' . $_FILES['file']['name']);
    }

?>
```

Si hay un error de subida lo podrás ver en la consola.

Comment: SIgue dando error, solo dice: 1

Comment: Puede deberse al `post_max_size`, si tienes acceso al `php.ini` del servidor, puedes modificar el `post_max_size` y reiniciar el servidor.

Comment: Tienes razón, es el peso del archivo. Muchas gracias!!